# Fetch a message (by ID) and edit it

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to edit a message the bot sent, in a different function.

```
const msg = message.channel.fetchMessage(msgId);
msg.edit(embed);
```

Didn't work because msg.edit is not a function.

```
message.channel.messages.fetch({around: "352292052538753025", limit: 1})
  .then(messages => {
    messages.first().edit("test");
  });
```

Didn't work because .fetch is not a function.

```
function update(msgId, time, channelid, prize, winnersInt, message) {

    setTimeout(function(){ 

        let gtime = time/3600000 + " hours remaining!";
        if(time < 3600000) {
            gtime = time/60000 + " minuets remaining!";
        }

        console.log(gtime + "p: " + prize);

        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("#7289da")
                        .setTitle("Giveaway!")
            .addField('Prize: ', prize)
            .addField('Amount of winners: ', winnersInt)
                       .addField('Time: ', gtime)
        const msg = message.channel.fetchMessage(msgId);
        msg.edit(embed);

        time - 60000;

        if(time > 0) {
                 update(msgId, time, channel, prize, winnersInt, message);
        }

    }, 60000);


}
```

I expect the message to be edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working.

Used this:

```
message.channel.fetchMessages({around: msgId, limit: 1})
    .then(msg => {
        const fetchedMsg = msg.first();
        fetchedMsg.edit(embed);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This is for v11. For those people using v12, use `message.channel.messages.fetch` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Old publication but may help those currently looking for it.

For V.13 it can be used this way:

```
<#Channel>.messages.fetch('messageID').then(msg => msg.edit('newMessage'))
```

I tested it that way and it worked perfectly.